# MVC3 ViewBag not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my action controller I am setting the following:

```
    ViewBag.headerinfo = "ddddddddddd";
    ViewBag.Info = "abc";
```

In my _Layout view I have:

```
<div id="header_infobox"> 
    @ViewBag.Info  bbbbb
    @ViewBag.headerinfo
</div>
```

When it comes to dispaly all I see is bbbbb. I can't understand why ViewBag doesn't work. I hope someone can give me advice.

Thanks,

Melissa

Comment: Are you sure the code in the controller is actually executed? Can you put a breakpoint and check?

Comment: We will need more info. I just tried it in a newly created mvc 3 application (your exact code), and I get `abc bbbbb ddddddddddd`.

Comment: Could you post the code for the entire action controller?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  For me, it was because I was returning RedirectToAction instead of just returning the View.  When you RedirectToAction, it apparently clears out the ViewBag.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

simply write

```
return View();
```

RedirectToAction("Index") , clears ViewBag

Answer (score 1):

Works great (newly created ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default Visual Studio template):

Controller (`~/Controllers/HomeController.cs`):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.headerinfo = "ddddddddddd";
        ViewBag.Info = "abc";
        return View();
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
<div id="header_infobox"> 
    @ViewBag.Info  bbbbb
    @ViewBag.headerinfo
</div>
```

Resulting HTML (as seen in browser view source):

```
<div id="header_infobox"> 
    abc  bbbbb
    ddddddddddd
</div>
```